# MySql Doctrine: find if given variable is IN array property

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have class Task with `categories` array of integers property

```
class Task{
      /**
       * @var array
       *
       * @ORM\Column(name="categories", type="array", nullable=true)
       */
private $categories;
 }
```

now in controller I am trying to build query which would check if `category id` variable is in `categories` array of the task

```
  $qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CoreBundle:Task')->createQueryBuilder('t');
  $qb->where(':category IN (t.categories)')
                    ->setParameter('category', $category);
```

This gives me error:

```
 [Syntax Error] line 0, col 140: Error: Expected Literal, got "t";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge this isn't possible in Doctrine directly as the array isn't technically an array until it has been unserialized from the database.

The only way I know to get the result you are looking for is to treat your database value as a string and search for the required string in that value using a `like` with wildcards.

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CoreBundle:Task')->createQueryBuilder('t');
$qb->where('t.categories LIKE :category')
   ->setParameter('category', '%'.$category.'%');
```