# Doctrine check if parameter value exists in entity array property

Tags: arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an array property inside my entity which contains series of dates in 'd/m/Y' format.

I'm trying to write a query which will select all instances of entity which don't have some date passed as argument to repository method in that array property.

I tried with:

```
 ->andWhere(
      $qb->expr()->notLike('u.datesBooked', ':date')
 )
```

and

```
 ->andWhere(
      $qb->expr()->notIn($date->format('d/m/Y'), 'u.datesBooked')
 )
```

with no luck, i get the wrong results. Is this even possible on database level?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39229713/1791606 . You would need to use `->where('u.datesBooked like :datesBooked')->setParameter('datesBooked', '%'.$date->format('d/m/Y').'%')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
->andWhere('u.datesBooked != :date')
->setParameter('date', $date);
```